# Create product variantion programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create product variation in woocommerce and using following code for insert variation post type.

```
foreach ($book_tag as $bookTag) {
    $post_name = 'ABE-'.$post_id.'book-type'.$bookTag;
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'BookType ' . $bookTag . ' for #' . $post_id,
        'post_name' => $post_name,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'product_variation',
        'guid' => home_url() . '/?product_variation=' . $post_name
    );
    $attID = wp_insert_post($my_post);
    update_post_meta($attID, 'book_type', $bookTag);
    update_post_meta($attID, '_price', $bookPrice);
    update_post_meta($attID, '_regular_price', $bookPrice);
    update_post_meta($attID, '_sale_price', $salePrice );
    update_post_meta($attID, '_sku', $post_name);
    update_post_meta($attID, '_virtual', 'no');
    update_post_meta($attID, '_downloadable', 'yes');
    update_post_meta($attID, '_manage_stock', 'no');
    update_post_meta($attID, '_stock_status', 'instock');
}
```

This is working fine but it is not set auto book type, i have to select attribute from the drop down option but i want it should auto selected attribute according attribute values.
Following screenshot which is showing to me:

[image]

but i want like following screenshot

[image]

So can you help me how do set attribute for variation products, my code is perfect or something do else.

Comment: LoicTheAztec, trying to insert variations product and i have already set attributes book type(Adobe PDF and epub) but when i run my code and check the variations products it give select option (see screenshot-1) but i want when i insert variations then i have not to be select book type, it set auto attribute value in select field, it should be show like screenshot-2

Answer (score 1):

I was entering wrong attribute name so i have corrected that like below:

```
update_post_meta($attID, 'attribute_book-type', $bookTag);
```

Here book-type is my attribute name which would be passed.